# How to stop scrolling from changing workspaces in i3 on CrunchBang++?

Tags: virtualbox, crunchbang, scrolling, workspaces, i3

I installed CrunchBang++ on a VirtualBox machine. I installed a few packages from the welcome script and the VirtualBox guest additions. I then installed i3 and set it as my window manager by creating `~/.xsession` with

```
exec /usr/bin/i3
```

as contents.

Everything works as intended with one exception: When I scroll up or down on the mouse wheel, while simultaneously moving the mouse vertically, the current workspace is changed. I'm not sure if X, SLiM and i3 or any other process is causing this. What is the cause of this problem and how do I stop it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1509619#p1509619) from Arch Linux Forums suggested, the problem was with VirtualBox rather than any other component. Simply **disabling automatic mouse integration** fixed the problem.

I'm not sure exactly why this is causing problems. An even better answer would of course be one that solves this without disabling automatic mouse integration.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but a suggestion on how you might find the answer.

Try running **xev**,
You should be able to confirm that scrolling up/down in the *xev* window produces logs with mouse button 4 and 5 e.g.:

```
ButtonRelease event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0xc4, subw 0x0, time 169151426, (78,60), root:(142,831),
    state 0x800, button 4, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 46, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0xc4, subw 0x0, time 169151506, (78,60), root:(142,831),
    state 0x0, button 5, same_screen YES
```

If its not it, it might be an X configuration problem, i.e. your mouse scroll inputs are somehow mapped to some other key events. But I think the first place to look would be in the i3 configuration. I assume the desktop switching behavior would be a feature and therefor there might be an option where it is bound to a key(s) in the configuration.

Basically; figure out what events mouse scrolls are producing, then grep configs for them.